# Predetecting collision on projectile with parabola in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, collision

I have a mini game that launches projectiles with a force and angle and takes into account a force pulling down (gravity) and a constant friction (wind friction). The idea is to have a mini game like "worms" where you can shoot and destroy stuff.

I got this working fine but with small fast projectiles I'm having the typical problem that it sometimes goes through. So I was thinking maybe I could pre-draw the parabola first with a line and detect where it interesects with one of the objects (which are rectangular).

I'm not quite sure how to do this, right at this moment I can actually draw a quite accurate path using the "lineTo" method, but that's all, I'm not sure it's useful for any collission pre-calculation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use any kind of engine? Most of them have properties to prevent fast moving objects not to register a collision ...

Comment: rather tricky to answer without code :) if you've done a custom engine, then you must have some kind of Delta Time somewhere. if you reduce it then you can calculate "slower" motion of an object. maybe isolating the physics solver to have it perform a calculation for any object is a good idea too.

Comment: mmm true story, I need to get home and post some code. Thanks :) I'm not using any engines btw. I guess if I managed to detect where a line collides with a rectangular shape I could manage to detect the exact point. Anyway I will edit to post some code later.